# What is the difference between Elastic Beanstalk and CloudFormation for a .NET project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I have developed a .NET MVC application and have started playing around with AWS and deploying it via the Visual Studio Toolkit. I have successfully deployed the application using the Elastic Beanstalk option in the toolkit.

As I was going over the tutorials for deploying .NET apps to AWS with the toolkit, I noticed there are tutorials for deploying with [both Elastic Beanstalk and CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/). What is the difference between these two?

From what I can tell, it seems like they both essentially are doing the same thing - making it easier to deploy your application to the AWS cloud (setting up EC2 instances, load balancer, auto-scaling, etc). I have tried reading up on them both, but I can't seem to get anything other than a bunch of buzz-words that sound like the same thing to me. I even found an [FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/faqs/#3) on the AWS website that is supposed to answer this exact question, yet I don't really understand.

Should I be using one or the other? Both?

Answer (score 304, accepted):

They're actually pretty different. Elastic Beanstalk is intended to make developers' lives easier.  CloudFormation is intended to make systems engineers' lives easier.

Elastic Beanstalk is a PaaS-like layer on top of AWS's IaaS services which abstracts away the underlying EC2 instances, Elastic Load Balancers, auto-scaling groups, etc.  This makes it a lot easier for developers, who don't want to be dealing with all the systems stuff, to get their application quickly deployed on AWS.  It's very similar to other PaaS products such as Heroku, EngineYard, Google App Engine, etc.  With Elastic Beanstalk, you don't need to understand how any of the underlying magic works.

CloudFormation, on the other hand, doesn't automatically do anything.  It's simply a way to define all the resources needed for deployment in a huge JSON/YAML file.  So a CloudFormation template might actually create two Elastic Beanstalk environments (production and staging), a couple of ElasticCache clusters, a DynamoDB table, and then the proper DNS in Route53.  I then upload this template to AWS, walk away, and 45 minutes later everything is ready and waiting.  Since it's just a plain-text JSON/YAML file, I can stick it in my source control which provides a great way to version my application deployments.  It also ensures that I have a repeatable, "known good" configuration that I can quickly deploy in a different region.

Comment: @xxkylexx FYI: "EBS" refers to the AWS service named "Elastic Block Store".  I think you mean to say "Elastic Beanstalk" instead of "EBS".

Comment: I think they used and automated Cloud Formation template to create the Elastic Beanstalk environment for the application you have created - .Net or whatever ... FWIW

Answer (score 89):

For getting started quickly deploying a standard .NET web-application, **Elastic Beanstalk** is the right service for you.

[image: App Services Comparison Graphic]

#### [**AWS CloudFormation**](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/): "Template-Driven Provisioning"

> AWS CloudFormation gives developers and systems administrators an easy way to create and manage a collection of related AWS resources, provisioning and updating them in an orderly and predictable fashion.

CloudFormation (CFn) is a lightweight, low-level abstraction over existing AWS APIs. Using a static JSON/YAML [template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-guide.html) document, you declare a set of [Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resources-section-structure.html) (such as an [EC2 instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html) or an [S3 bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html)) that correspond to CRUD operations on the AWS APIs.

When you create a CloudFormation stack, CloudFormation calls the corresponding APIs to create the associated Resources, and when you delete a stack, CloudFormation calls the corresponding APIs to delete them. [Most (but not all) AWS APIs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html) are supported.

#### [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/): "Web Apps Made Easy"

> AWS Elastic Beanstalk is an easy-to-use service for deploying and scaling web applications and services developed with [Java](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.html), [.NET](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.html), [PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_eb.html), [Node.js](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.html), [Python](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-apps.html), [Ruby](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby.html), [Go](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_go.html), and [Docker](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html) on familiar servers such as Apache, Nginx, Passenger, and IIS.
>
> You can simply upload your code and Elastic Beanstalk automatically handles the deployment, from capacity provisioning, load balancing, auto-scaling to application health monitoring.

Elastic Beanstalk (EB) is a higher-level, managed 'platform as a service' (PaaS) for hosting web applications, similar in scope to [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). Rather than deal with low-level AWS resources directly, EB provides a fully-managed platform where you [create an application environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.environments.html) using a [web interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-console.html), select which [platform](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html) your application uses, create and upload a [source bundle](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html), and EB handles the rest.

Using EB, you get all sorts of built-in features for [monitoring your application environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-health.html) and [deploying new versions of your application](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.deploy-existing-version.html).

Under the hood, EB uses CloudFormation to create and manage the application's various AWS resources. You can customize and extend the default EB environment by adding [CloudFormation Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html) to an [EB configuration file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) deployed with your application.

#### Conclusion

If your application is a standard web-tier application using one of Elastic Beanstalk's supported platforms, and you want easy-to-manage, highly-scalable hosting for your application, **use Elastic Beanstalk**.

If you:

- Want to manage all of your application's AWS resources directly;
- Want to manage or heavily customize your instance-provisioning or deployment process;
- Need to use an application platform not supported by Elastic Beanstalk; or
- Just don't want/need any of the higher-level Elastic Beanstalk features

then **use CloudFormation directly** and avoid the added configuration layer of Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 18):

Cloud Formation is a service that lets you deploy AWS services.  You create a template file that describes which services you want.  When you deploy that template, Cloud Formation creates the resources for you as a "package".  All the resources you defined in your template are started and terminated together.  Examples of types of resources that can be created with Cloud Formation are:  S3, EC2 instances, AutoScaling, DynamoDb, etc.  For EC2, Cloud Formation also gives you the ability to make use of "cfn-init" scripts; which can be used in conjunction with the template to boot strap your instances.

Elastic Beanstalk uses Cloud Formation templates and scipts to: 1. Create a Load Balancer and Auto Scaling Group, 2. Copy your code to S3, 3. Bootstrap an Ec2 instance to Download the code from S3 and deploy it.

Cloud Formation is not as easy to use as EB, but it is much more powerful, because you can create resources other than EC2 instances, control how the cfn-init script, and etc.

Answer (score 11):

There are other differences worth noting. Elastic beanstalk is designed as a container for a single app. I've a set of several websites and services but found it very difficult to deploy multiple websites with beanstalk and was advised, after several attempts, by AWS help to use cloud formation in this situation as it has the extra flexibility.
Theres a really helpful article on bootstrapping AWS cloud formation and updating a running site [here](http://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/08/05/bootstrapping-on-aws/) thats much clearer than the AWS pages. Still trying to work out if we can deploy from VS straight to the cloud formation template stored on S3 and get it to auto update like beanstalk...

Answer (score 4):

Both are for provisioning infrastructure; but they differ in their approach.

**Beanstalk:** The starting point is the code. I have a NodeJs code I want to upload & run it; please provision the infrastructure for me. (PaaS) Platform as a Service

**CloudFormation:** The starting point is the infrastructure. Please create an EC2 instance, with one LoadBalancer, Security Group etc so that I can uploaded my NodeJs code to it. Infrastructure as Code  (IaC).

Answer (score 3):

These services are designed to complement each other. AWS Elastic Beanstalk provides an environment to easily deploy and run applications in the cloud. It is integrated with developer tools and provides a one-stop experience for you to manage the lifecycle of your applications. AWS CloudFormation is a convenient provisioning mechanism for a broad range of AWS and third party resources. It supports the infrastructure needs of many different types of applications such as existing enterprise applications, legacy applications, applications built using a variety of AWS resources and container-based solutions (including those built using AWS Elastic Beanstalk).

AWS CloudFormation supports Elastic Beanstalk application environments as one of the AWS resource types. This allows you, for example, to create and manage an AWS Elastic Beanstalk–hosted application along with an RDS database to store the application data. In addition to RDS instances, any other supported AWS resource can be added to the group as well.

Answer (score 2):

Elastic Beanstalk automatically handles the deployment, from capacity provisioning, load balancing, auto-scaling to application health monitoring based on the code you upload to it, where as CloudFormation is an automated provisioning engine designed to deploy entire cloud environments via a JSON script.

Answer (score 0):

Beanstalk: Gives the developer the ability to manage only code and not systems

Cloud Formation: Simplifies and makes everything easier for a Systems Engineer

If a developer or the dev team is looking for a quick MVP testing, the best option is to quickly get deployed with Beanstalk and check.

When a AWS migration happens, systems engineer will get involved in provisioning and Cloud Formation will help a lot and give much more granular control.

Answer (score 0):

**Beanstack** internally uses **cloudformation**.

Comment: very low quality answer!! it could be said as a comment!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**Beanstalk** - Basically helpful for software developers.

**Example** : You want to start the PC quickly and run an application. You don't buy the PC items (harddisk, ram, Processor) separately. You buy a whole CPU or a laptop of a required config. You dont care how its running inside as you want your application to run for you. Beanstalk gives you this feature of everything ready made with no worries.

**Cloudformation** -  Basically helpful for system engineer/ Hardware.

**Example** : You want to assemble 100's of PC's and give it to the developers then instead of assembling so many PC's you can just give a list of items and the PC is assembled for you by the retailer.
Similarly create a template and send it to cloudformation it will finish your work with no effort.